# Magento 2 : By Default is There Page That Groups All Featured Products

Tags: magento2, product, category, featured-product

I need to create featured page / category where all featured products are grouped.

By default I create an hidden (from the menu) category and I add products both to featured category and with featured flag.

I was wondering if there is nicer way to do this. Is there already a page, by default, that includes all featured products? Or is there a way to automate adding a product to a category if it gets featured?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign product to featured category if it gets featured using observer. You can easily use `catalog_product_save_after` event.

I am assuming that you already know how to create a module in `M2`.

Put this `events.xml` in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\etc\adminhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And put your `Productsaveafter.php` in below path

app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Observer\

```
<?php

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
        $_isFeatured = $_product->getIsFeatured();
        if($_isFeatured == 1){
            //your further code here to assign this product to featured category
        }
    }   
}
```